# What am I asked to do when $\Delta =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, operator-theory, partial-derivative

I have a function F$$F=F(t,x,y,z)=e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{4t}}$$

and with this, we define a function G as $$G=G(t)=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty }\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty }F(t,x,y,z) dxdydz$$

and also a function H is $$H=H(t,x,y,z)=\frac{\Delta F(t,x,y,z)}{G(t)}$$where $$\Delta =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$$

I need to evaluate $$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{ \infty } H(t,1,2,3) dt$$

but I am not familiar with an operator so I don't know what $\Delta$ tells me to do with $F$.

Can anyone help me?

---

What I have found

$$G(t)=8\pi t \sqrt{\pi t}$$

Comment: Actually operator noted like that acts as a dot product $$ \Delta(F) =\Delta \cdot F$$

Comment: @edx do you mean$ \Delta F(t,x,y,z)=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2 F}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial z^2}$?

Comment: Yes that't it, you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Delta =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}
$$
is a short way to define expressions like $\Delta F(t,x,y,z)$.  So, in particular,
it tells you to do something with partial derivatives:
$$
\Delta F(t,x,y,z) = 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}F(t,x,y,z)+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}F(t,x,y,z)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}F(t,x,y,z) .
$$
so, what do do if $F$ is given by
$$
F(t,x,y,z) = e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)/(4t)}
$$
Proceed step-by-step
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F = e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)/(4t)}\;\cdot\frac{-x}{2t}
$$
(chain rule), then
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} F = e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)/(4t)}\;\cdot\left(\frac{x}{2t}\right)^2 + e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)/(4t)}\cdot\frac{-1}{2t}
= e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)/(4t)}\;\cdot\frac{x^2-2t}{4t^2}
$$
(product rule).

I leave some for you.  Next do $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} F$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} F$.  Then add the three together.